# How to access a dynamically created element

Tags: c#, watin

I am using Watin to test a website. It contains a  which is created dynamically on clicking a tablecell. How can I access the dynamically created . The issue is the  is deleted after a short span of time (even before the control can move to next line)

```
if(tablecell.exists)
{
    tablecell.ClickNoWait(); //this creates the dynamic <div>
    if(div.exists) //the control does not go inside 
    {
        //code to edit div contents.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
browser.WaitUntil
```